# What are possible pitfalls when migrating from Flex SDK 4.0.0 to Flex SDK 4.1.0 (or later)?

Tags: flex4, migration

We have a large game built with Flex SDK 4.0.0, using Flex 4 as the GUI framework and (largely) PureMVC as the architectural framework.

Since we need to add right-to-left text/layout support to the game in the near future and the `layoutDirection` property is only available in Flex SDK 4.1.0 or later, we obviously need to change the SDK with which we build our project.

Are there any known pitfalls and issues that we could run into when making the switch? What are the things to keep a close eye one (ANT tasks? namespaces? custom components? charting?) because they could break during the migration?

Comment: i would like to mention too that 4.1 and 4.5+ are not fully compatible. better skip 4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally decided to make a bigger step and go directly for SDK 4.6.0/FP11.1 and while doing so we will be refactoring lots of stuff anyway.